# XHTML anchor link with background image and no text

Tags: xhtml, anchor, background-image

Is it possible to have anchor links no text inside that has a background image and fixed dimensions and still be good for SEO?

**Example CSS:**

```
a{display:block;width:50px;height:20px;background-image:url('images/background.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:0 0;}

a:hover img{background-position:0 -20px;}
```

**Example HTML:**
`<a href="#"></a>`

Comment: If it is a link, then it does something when you click on it. If it does something, the user needs to know what it does. Therefore it needs content. A **background** image is not content. Use an `<img>` with an `alt` attribute and stop obsessing about micro-optimisations against secret algorithms.

Comment: I have reasons to ask for that, thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the image has text in it or you simply want to add its description, one thing you can do to help SEO and accessibility is to give the anchor a title and content with a large negative text-indent, like adding this to your `a` CSS:

```
display:block;
text-indent:-9999em;
```

...with the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="IMAGE TEXT">IMAGE TEXT</a>
```

Comment: That's something I could do thanks, however I was never a fan of doing this kind of text hiding. Thanks again!

Comment: If the text is in the background image however it's not hiding, it's providing it for screen readers that otherwise wouldn't see it without detrimentally affecting your design.

Comment: Yup, I know this method well, it just slipped my mind. I just don't like it too much, but it could be the best way of doing this now.

Comment: @mVChr; You might look at this http://luigimontanez.com/2010/stop-using-text-indent-css-trick/

Comment: What if you're using image sprites as the background in css? The main goal with text indent there isn't to trick Google.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by neXib's comment on another answer.

HTML:

```
<a href="/home" title="Homepage" class="home">
    <div><img src="/images/sprite.png" alt="Home" /></div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    display: block;
}
.home div {
    width: 84px;
    height: 27px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.home div img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -65px;
    left: -20px;
}
```

So long as the div has 'overflow: hidden' and fixed dimensions the image inside can be positioned within to only display the part of the sprite you want.

SEO was a concern for me too and I think this solution will work fine.

Comment: Only problem with this is that if the images are turned off or can't be found then the alt text is going to be hidden because of the positioning. But it is still better than an empty anchor tag and using css background image positioning.

Answer (score 1):

The search engine can't read it, so how would it be good for SEO? More importantly, why do you want to do this, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to use sprites, this being the main purpose. Very very good point about engines not being able to read content, I was thinking they would follow the link and read the content of the page, didn't think of it how you put it. Thanks!

Comment: Having read your other comments, just a quick thought. You could perhaps put your background/sprite image in the link, as an img inside the a, and then offset the image inside the a tag using CSS on hover. (I haven't thought this through, but could be something to look at if you want to take this path). I'm only using sprites for buttons/links when the site isn't searchable personally.

Answer (score 1):

Use alt and title attribute, but having no content inside the tags is pointless.I think that there is a serious risk that you will be penalized in the search results!

Again, why are you trying this. Are you doing buttons that are linking to another page or that 
run a javascript function?

Comment: They are basically links with images, only I wanted the images to be sprites because of a problem with the client's bandwith and the large amounts of such links. Normally I put images inside the links and let JavaScript swap the images.

Comment: Also, they are regular buttons, but text is on the image and I want to have sprites where hover changes background-position.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt this fix the problem?

```
<a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
```

Well this is a bit old question but just want opinion on this!

Comment: My initial approach was wrong, no text is meaningless so bad for accessibility and search engines. Adding `&nbsp;` doesn't help, it just ads a few extra chars.