# Remove text on menu item

Tags: html, css

I have a menu structure:

```
<ul id="footer-nav">
    <li id="button1"><a href="#page-1">a</a></li>
    <li id="button2"><a href="#page-2">a</a></li>
    <li id="button3"><a href="#page-3">a</a></li>
    <li id="button4"><a href="#page-4">a</a></li>
    <li id="button5"><a href="#page-5">a</a></li>
    <li id="button6"><a href="#page-6">a</a></li>
    <li id="button7"><a href="#page-7">a</a></li>
    <li id="button8"><a href="#page-8">a</a></li>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul#footer-nav {background:url(images/footer-nav_bg.png) no-repeat;height:52px;position:relative;left:50%;bottom:22px;width:272px;}
ul#footer-nav li {background: url(images/footer-nav-li_bg.png) no-repeat;height: 20px;width: 20px;top: 45%;float: left;position: relative;margin-right: 10px;left: 8%;}
```

When i click a menu item, go to page. It's ok. But i want, no text on menu item so when i remove `a` text on my structure, unclickable my menu item. How can i solve it?

Comment: And how do you remove the text ?

Comment: @adeneo I believe the `a` text is inserted for testing only.  They apparently would manually delete the `a` text from the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `a` does not take up any space when empty - and therefore not clickable.

You can add the following CSS to solve this:

```
ul#footer-nav li a {
    display: inline-block; /* important for the width and height to take effect */
    width: 60px; /* or whatever */
    height: 20px; /* or whatever */
}
```

Comment: For accessibility, I would at a minimum include a `title` attribute in your anchor tags.  This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748454/xhtml-anchor-link-with-background-image-and-no-text) covers more on this.

Comment: Maybe using `width:100%;` and ``height:100%;` would be better ?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the text the  will have no height. Change your css to include a width and height for the anchor tag and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#footer-nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 20px;
}
```